# Movie about a guy who receives a mysterious list of all his girlfriends, past and future

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched a movie a few years ago, and now can't remember the title.

The main character received a mysterious email at work containing a list of every woman he had, or would have sex with--past and future.

I can provide more details if necessary, but I'm sure this will be enough for anyone who's seen the movie (and remembers the title) to identify it.

Comment: Please do provide more detail.  The more fleshed out the question is, there is a higher chance for upvotes and answers.

Answer (score 9):

The movie is Sex and Death 101. It stars Simon Baker (The Mentalist) as a guy who receives a list of all of the women he has or will ever date. At first he thinks of this as a surefire sex list but as events plays out he starts to realize the downside. He can't ever have a date that works out that is not on the list even if he finds the perfect woman for him. Also he only gets their first initial and a last name. It also stars Winona Ryder. It's a pretty decent movie overall.